# Build versus Runtime Dependencies in Nix

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I am just starting to get to grips with Nix, so apologies if I missed the answer to my question in the docs.

I want to use Nix to setup a secure production machine with the minimal set of libraries and executables. I don't want any compilers or other build tools present because these can be security risks.

When I install some packages, it seems that they depend on only the minimum set of runtime dependencies. For example if I install `apache-tomcat-8.0.23` then I get a Java runtime (JRE) and the pre-built JAR files comprising Tomcat.

On the other hand, some packages seem to include a full build toolchain as dependencies. Taking another Java-based example, when I install `spark-1.4.0` Nix pulls down the Java development kit (JDK) which includes a compiler, and it also pulls the Maven build tool etc.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. Do Nix packages make any distinction between build and runtime dependencies?
2. Why do some packages appear to depend on build tools whereas others only need runtime? Is this all down to how the package author wrapped up the application?
3. If a package contains build dependencies that I don't want, is there anything that I, as the operator, can do about it except design my own alternative packaging for the same application?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. The runtime dependencies are a subset of the build-time dependencies that Nix determines automatically by scanning the generated output for the hash part of each build-time dependencies' store path. For example, if you build a package using the compiler `/nix/store/abcdef...-foo-1.20`, then Nix will scan all files in the generated output for the hash bit `abcdef...`. If that hash is found, then the output is assumed to reference the compiler in some way, so it's kepts as a runtime dependency. If that hash does not occur, however, then the generated output has no reference to the compiler and therefore cannot access it at runtime, so `foo-1.20` is treated as a build-time-only dependency.
2. Some packages record large parts of their build environment for informational/debugging purposes. Perl, for example, stores every little detail about the tools used to compile it, so all those store paths end up being treated as runtime dependencies despite the fact that Perl doesn't actually need them at runtime, but Nix can't know: it just knows that the Perl store path *references* those tools. Now, Nixpkgs maintainers usually make an effort to clean that up, i.e. by pruning the logfile that contains all those store paths from the installation, etc., but for sure there are plenty of packages in the database still that haven't been optimized to that end yet.
3. Let's assume that you'd like to compile a version of `openssh` that does not depend on PAM. Then you can remove the build input from the expression by means of an override, i.e. you replace the `pam` argument that's normally passed to the `openssh` build function with `null`. To do that, store the following file in `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`

   ```
   {
     packageOverrides = super: let self = super.pkgs; in {
       openssh-without-pam = super.openssh.override {
         pam = null;
       };
     };
   }
   ```

   and now install that package by running:

   ```
   $ nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -iA openssh-without-pam
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and comprehensive answer.

Comment: You mention "automatically by scanning the generated output", how does Nix actually do this? Does it work with dynamically executed paths via `exec` inside a binary? Or perhaps a generated config file storing the path to another package's binary?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, yes it seems that nix actually scan binaries for derivation hashes. Unfortunately, I'm not able to find actual code, but here is some details https://lethalman.blogspot.ru/2014/08/nix-pill-9-automatic-runtime.html

Comment: [Source reference](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/84f112b1c8d3c5181b7a9b11d309f14f1709480d/src/libstore/references.cc#L83-L119) :)

Comment: I found that this automatic scanning doesn't work for shell scripts however. So if your build produces a shell script, you need to somehow wrap to know about the PATH (like `makeWrapper`) or explicitly substitute executable invocations.